# Javascript image slideshow - mouseover

Tags: javascript, slideshow, mouseover

I am having a hard time searching for the answer to my problem.  Mainly because I have no idea how to ask it in a google/yahoo search.

My site:  http://www.wbsnightout.com/sidekick

On the right side I have three sponsor ad div's with images rotating.  Each image has a title and is a clickable link.  The only problem is, is that when you mouse over the image, the LINK and TITLE for the image BEHIND the shown image comes up.  When I click on it, it takes me to the wrong link, because it's the link for the image behind it.

Here is an example of my HTML:

```
    <div id="right-sponsor"> <!-- Begin right Sidebar -->
 <div class="advertiseSlides" id="sponsor2">
 <a title='Click for more Info!' href='http://www.ricochetsrapiddetail.net/' target='_blank' rel='nofollow'><img src='/images/advertise/ricochet_ad.jpg' alt='Ricochet's Rapid Detail' title='Ricochet's Rapid Detail' height='200' width='240' />
 </a>   </div>
```

This is pulled dynamically using php and mysql.

I have this before my closing body tag within a script tag

```
  initImageGallery('sponsor1', 5000);
```

And my javascript file can be found:  http://www.wbsnightout.com/sidekick/js/slideshow.js

I don't know much about javascript so I just used I script that I found online.

If you can answer or point me to a discussion or tutorial, that would be great!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this  (add 'z-index:9999;' to .advertiseSlides img in css

Comment: .advertiseSlides img{  z-index:9999;}

Comment: looks like javascript is off by 1 count

Comment: @Cocre80r I just tried that, but still the same problem.  I did notice when I inspect the element, watching one of the images as it cycles through the slideshow, the element style becomes "visible" before it is actually seen?  So as image 1 is actually visible image 2 switches from hidden to visible.